# Optimal number vertices in a game

Tags: mesh, game-engine, performance

I am creating a game and was wondering what a good number for the total number of vertices or triangles; either answer would be great.
What quantity can the Blender game engine handle rendering in real time without the frame rate getting too out of control? I prefer a frame rate above 30 fps.
The piece I'm asking about is the terrain I made. It will have 120,000 vertices in total, none of which are moving, and the player will probably see only 1000-2000 at a time (not sure if this makes a difference). I wasn't sure if this would be an issue as I am new to the game engine side of blender.

Comment: More information about the game you are making, and how the various elements lock together would be helpful in getting you an answer. it is conceivable that the optimum number of vertices might be different for an aircraft aerial battle game or first person shooter, than in a treasure hunt type game. In general, the faster something moves in game, the lower the number of vertices it should consist of; the slower an object moves, the greater the number it can have without adverse effects on frame rates.

Comment: This is a "just try it" question. It depends on that much factors that you will never get a clear statement on that. It simply depends too much on your situation (and the situation you are creating). - sorry, I know this is not the answer you are looking for.

Comment: Sorry I didn't specify more about the game the thing that I was really concerned about was the terrain I made.  It will have 120,000 vertices in total, none of which are moving, and the player will probably see only 1000-2000 at a time(not sure if this makes a difference).  I wasn't sure if this would be an issue as I am new to the game engine side of blender.  Thanks

Comment: It also depends a lot on the specifications of the computers your target audience will be using

Answer (score 1):

If this is the terrain we're talking about, 120k is probably a good number, seeing as the base reqs for a computer are 1,000,000 verts (without any other things, textures, filters, light). That mean most computers can handle vertex counts of up to 1mil.

The only problem I can see is in the fact that this is a terrain, and not a character, you said only 1-2k verts would be seen at a time, but that doesn't matter if the terrain is one object; Blender will still render the entire object even if only 1 vertex is visible.

So what to fix then? Generally, terrains don't need this amount of detail (right now I'm making one, several acres, and its pushing 30k), so to start with, you may wan to break it down into more base elements to free up resources for other rendering jobs. If its a city landscape, separate the buildings into their own objects, and get some LOD going for props. You may also want to break the landscape into more manageable chunks an area that would normally be blocked by a hill could be separated into its own object so that it only need to be rendered when called for. You could also use occlude objects. these basically ensure that any object that is hidden behind another won't be rendered. It seems intuitive, but really, blender renders anything inside your cameras view arc and clipping range whether or not it's behind another object.

There is a whole science behind game optimization, and youTube will probably be your best resource.